# Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment with NUnit3 and Google Test

Tags: tfs, automated-tests

We have the following setup for unit and functional testing in TFS (under Build Definitions in TFS)

1. Install our program into a clean VM.
2. Deploy test agent (default vstf_testagent.exe)
3. Run tests

Some of the tests are written in NUnit3 and the C++ test in Google Tests. So, they are not seen by the default test runner.

In Visual Studio, the test adapters work great to run the tests.

But, I can't seem to figure out how to install these test adapters to vstf_testagent.exe on the virtual machine so that it sees and runs all the tests.

I found this [page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/03/03/how-to-make-your-extension-visible-to-the-test-explorer-in-visual-studio-11/) on how to install agents but it is with using Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you deploy the test agent successful? Are you using the " Visual Studio test using Test Agent" after the deploy? And what's the result if you try to use  the local installed testagents ?

Comment: The MSTests unit tests run fine on the virtual machine using the default test agent. 
On local dev machine's Visual Studio, both the MSTests, NUnit3 and Google Test show up and run well with the adapter.
I can't figure out how to install these adapters on the virtual machine using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the test adapters to your project via Nuget and add a Nuget restore task in your build definition to restore the packages. "Run Functional Tests" task will search the test adapters in "packages" folder automatically.

> **Test Adapters:** There is no explicit field to specify Test Adapter path in the task. The task automatically searches for "packages"
>   directory that exists in the same folder as the .sln file (nuget
>   restored directory structure). If your adapters are in a different
>   directory or you did not copy over the source files, use a runsettings
>   file with TestAdaptersPaths as described at
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx

If the test adapters is in other folder, you can create a runsettings file and run the test with it.

Refer to this link for details: [Visual Studio Test using Test Agent Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/RunDistributedTests).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install **Visual Studio on your VM**.

After that the directly way to make NUnit adapters available is downloading them from [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/), unzip the `.vsix` extension file, then copy all the extension file in the folder just as the link mentioned in your question.

This operation **should be done in every machine where you deployed Test Agents** that will be used to run build with nunit tests. This can be annoying if you have lots of agents, if you prefer, **Test Runner** Task has an options to specify the path where the agent can find needed test runners.

You can also automate all the process by adding **Nunit3 Test Adapter nuget package** just as *Eddie* suggest to your test project, adding a standard Nuget Reference. Detail ways you can refer this blog: [nUnit and Jasmine.JS unit tests in TFS/VSO vNext build](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04aug15/nunit-and-jasmine-js-unit-tests-in-tfs-vso-vnext-build/)

> Nuget Package
>
> [NUnit 3 Test Adapter for Visual Studio 2012/13/15](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to copy the .dlls of your testadapter that you want to use directly from the nuget-package to the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions`of your computer where you want to run your tests.

Also see:
http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/06/04/running-unit-tests-on-different-machine-during-tfs-2015-build/